# Incompatible type error for string[]

Tags: java, arrays, incompatibletypeerror

Hi getting an error and don't know why. Here my code for a challenge.

```
    public class Solution {
    static void displayPathtoPrincess(int n, String [] grid){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m;
    m = in.nextInt();
    String grid[] = new String[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        grid[i] = in.next();


    }
    int[] x;
    x = new int[m-1];
    x[0] = 0;
    String p;
    String single[];
    single = new String[(m*m)];
    for(int i = 0; i < (m); i++){
    for(int b = 0; b <= m; b++){          
        single[b] = (grid[i].split("(?!^)"));

            System.out.println(p);
    }


    } 




displayPathtoPrincess(m,grid);
}
}
```

The code is not neat or anywhere near complete but when I run it I get this error:

```
Solution.java:29: error: incompatible types 
single[b] = (grid[i].split("(?!^)")); 
^ 
required: String 
found: String[] 
1 error
```

I then tried using a regular string thats not an array didnt work. I then tried to just put in a string where `grid[i]` is and that also didnt work. Im stuck any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please indent sample code when you post it.

Comment: Sry I just started can you explain what this means?

Comment: No worries!  Basically, ever time you type a {, lines after it should be indented ~4 spaces until you get to the }, so that it's easy to see what's inside of a { } block.  Two of your "for" statements do this correctly... but the third doesn't, which makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I will make sure to do that next time thanks for telling me.

Comment: No worries!  Welcome to Stack Overflow; there's a bunch to learn, but it's pretty damn interesting along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split()` method returns an array `String[]` and you are trying to insert array into `String`.

Just edit your code to this :

```
String single[][];
single = new String[(m * m)][];
for (int i = 0; i < (m); i++) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= m; b++) {
        single[i*m+b] = (grid[i].split("(?!^)"));
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
displayPathtoPrincess(m, grid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works but is there anyway where i can get it so a single string is assigned. For example is i have string "abc" can i get it to split and be Firstletter = "a" Seconfletter = "b" and Thridletter = "c". Right now it makes a array that looks like [a , b, c]. P.S I should of been more specific no fault to you.

Comment: @JTattack I don't understand what you are asking. Please be more clear.

Comment: Sorry. Right now it outprints a single array with each part that it broke up inside. I was wondering if it was possible to get each part .split broke up by itslef. Instead of [a, b, c] have it be [a] [b] [c]. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the help you pointed me in the right direction and i have figure it out.

Comment: Well it is good.But it is funny but I still didn't understood what you were trying to ask. Did you mean you wanted each character of the string?

Comment: Yeah. Im sorry I made it so confusing.

Comment: @JTattack You can accept an answer if you found it useful (specifically most useful). and upvote it if you found it good.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the `split()` method returns a String array `String[]`. But you are trying to assign it to a String `single[b]`.

Edit: `single[b]` is not an array. It's just a regular string. `single` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

String [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method returns an array and you cannot assign an array to string :

```
single[b] = (grid[i].split("(?!^)"));
```

hence the error. Probably you need to define single as two dimensional array and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you were intending to do:

```
String[] single = grid[i].split("(?!^)");
```

When you make the call to `String.split()` Java will return an already allocated `String[]` array.

Unfortunately, you never finished your code so we are limited from helping you much more than this.